Map Oracle JSON columns using JPA and Hibernate, ignore if value is null
@Type(type = "io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonType") @Column(name="Emp") private String Emp;
Error while execute empRepo.save(empEnity) (Emp is null)
SQL Error: 17004, SQLState: 99999
Invalid column type: 1111
Tried @Column(name="Emp", nullable = true) and @Nullable, but giving same error.
Using Oracle 23 AI, Hibernate 5, Spring-Data-JPA
How to ignore a specific field of entity in the insert query if the value is null.

You don't specify  neither the DB version, neither the DDL of the column...
Anyway you should start by checking that you are respecting the recommendations for ORACLE in the comments of the source code of the JsonType class: https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils/blob/master/hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63/src/main/java/io/hypersistence/utils/hibernate/type/json/JsonType.java
